# Redis Master/Slave different OS Platforms

Tags: linux, windows-server, stackexchange.redis, redis-server

Can Redis be run in a master/slave configuration with one instance being Redislabs' official Linux release and the other instance being Microsoft's Open Tech port?

I'm using stackexchange.redis for the application's transport layer and I'm currently experimenting with the most recent version of the windows port.

Comment: I have had no problems running a cluster with some linux nodes mixed with some windows nodes (Redis v3.0). But I'm running the linux version from redis.io, not the redislabs one.